# How to get browser console error messages using Selenium WebDriver + python

Tags: python, selenium, logging, browser, selenium-chromedriver

[Console error png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wan1s.png) We have been trying to print the console errors for the particular site by using the following code. But we are unable to catch console errors. Can anyone give quick response
But we are getting

Line of Code :

```
driver.get_log('browser')
```

Error :

```
[{u'source': u'deprecation', u'message': u"https://xxxxx/static/vendor/vendor.bundle.js?v=16 902 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.", u'timestamp': 1515593047810, u'level': u'WARNING'}]
```

Line of Code :

```
driver.get_log('driver')
```

Error :

```
[{u'timestamp': 1515593061561, u'message': u'Unable to evaluate script: disconnected: not connected to DevTools\n', u'level': u'WARNING'}, {u'timestamp': 1515593071847, u'message': u'Unable to evaluate script: disconnected: not connected to DevTools\n', u'level': u'WARNING'}]
```

Code Block :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabilities['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('url')
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
elem.send_keys('xxxx')
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
elem1.send_keys('xxxx')
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-info')
elem2.click()
driver.get('url')
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print entry
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to see exactly, but you could import the exceptions module for selenium: `from selenium.common.exceptions import *`. Then you can write try/except blocks to catch and report specific Selenium exceptions.

Comment: What do you mean by console errors?

Comment: @RonNorris   we have to print the errors whatever we are getting in the console.

Comment: @Qwerty javascript console errors or messages

Comment: Is it that you are trying to read the `Browser Console Logs` through your program?

Comment: This seems weird, but could you try putting your for loop in a worker thread? I'd also try putting a sleep before your for loop to see if that resolves anything. If it does then you may have to wait for something on the page to make sure it's finished doing whatever it's doing.

Comment: yeah @DebanjanB I am trying to read browser console errors.

Comment: Can you help me with a valid usecase to read the `browser console errors` and as per your code trial `print entry` back to console ?

Comment: Hier ist the solution for c#: [How to get browser console error messages using Selenium WebDriver + C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351421/how-to-get-browser-console-error-messages-using-selenium-webdriver-c-sharp/70351422#70351422)

Answer (score 7):

this `Error:` looks like a JS error being printed:

```
[{u'source': u'deprecation', u'message': 
 u"https://xxxxx/static/vendor/vendor.bundle.js?v=16 902 Synchronous 
 XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental 
 effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check 
 https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.", u'timestamp': 1515593047810, u'level': 
 u'WARNING'}]
```

I believe what that is outputing is what you are looking for.

Example from console on `https://stackoverflow.com/`:
[image]

and this is my output from `for log in driver.get_log('browser'): print(log)`:

```
{'level': 'SEVERE', 'message': 'https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js - 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET', 'source': 'network', 
'timestamp': 1515630280361}
{'level': 'SEVERE', 'message': 'https://js-sec.indexww.com/ht/p/185901-
159836282584097.js - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT', 'source': 
'network', 'timestamp': 1515630288646}
{'level': 'SEVERE', 'message': 
'https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js - Failed to load resource: 
net::ERR_TIMED_OUT', 'source': 'network', 'timestamp': 1515630288785}
```