# How to get browser console error messages using Selenium WebDriver + C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I want to collect all the console error messages that appear in the console with Selenium WebDriver + C #. I just want console errors like

*Console errors*
[image: Console errors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps to collect browser logs and then output them.

---

**1 - Create a function for collecting error logs**
This function return a list of browser errors. like this:

```
    private List<string> GetBrowserError()
    {
        ILogs logs = this.Driver.Manage().Logs;
        var logEntries = logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser); // LogType: Browser, Server, Driver, Client and Profiler
        List<string> errorLogs = logEntries.Where(x => x.Level == LogLevel.Severe).Select(x => x.Message).ToList();
        return errorLogs;
     }
```

**2 - Add the logs to TestContext**
Like this:

```
    private void AddBorwserLogs()
    {
        string errors = "\n \n*** Errors ***\n \n";
        List<string> errorLogs = this.GetBrowserError();

        if (errorLogs.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var logEntry in errorLogs)
            {
                errors = errors + $"{logEntry}\n";
            }

        // Add errors to TestContext
        TestContext.WriteLine($"{errors}\nNumber of browser errors is: {errorLogs.Count}");
        }
     }
```

**3 - Function calling**
Call the `AddBorwserLogs()` function before test teardown. Like this:

```
    [TestCleanup]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        this.AddBorwserLogs();
        this.Driver.Close();
        this.Driver.Quit();
     }
```

**Don't forget to initialize the WebDriver**
Like this:

```
    public IWebDriver Driver;
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
    
        this.Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        this.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 70);
        var url = "https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/";
        this.Driver.Url = url;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work with Selenium 3.141.0, you need to upgrade or downgrade to avoid a null reference exception on this line: logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser)

Comment: This was a bug in .NET. It was fixed with Selenium 4. Therefore this solution only works with Selenium 4 and higher

Comment: I'm using selenium 4.8.2/ChromeDriver 111.x and needed to add options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All) to get this to work.